# Choose selectbox option based on a number in an inputbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, onchange

I wrote the below function to append new selectbox onchange of my selectbox.

this part of code works well for me.

my question is how to select an option of my main selectbox based on value of inputbox with classname childcount?

I mean if it was 2 choose an option with value 2 ?
is there a way ?
here is my snippet :

```js
$(function() {
  $(".button-click-child a").on("click", function() {
    var button = $(this);
    var oldVal = parseInt(button.closest("ul").prev().val());
    var newVal = (button.text() == "+") ? oldVal + 1 : (oldVal > 0) ? oldVal - 1 : 0;
    button.closest("ul").prev().val(newVal);
    button.closest("ul").next().val(newVal+',');
    $(".cat_textbox").each(function() {
      var cat = $(this).prev('span').text();
      total_value += cat + ": " + $(this).val() + "، ";
    });

    if (oldVal < newVal) {
      $('.childDropdowns').append(createChildDropdown(newVal));
    } else if (oldVal > newVal) {
      destroyChildDropdown($('.childDropdowns'), newVal);
    }
  
  })
})
 function childAge(a){
   $(a).each(function(){
   age=$(a).val();
   
    $(a).closest(".countRoom").find(".selectAge").empty();
    for(var j=1;j<=age;j++){
     $(a).closest(".countRoom").css("width","100%").find(".selectAge").append('<div class="age"><label>Age of Child' + j + '</label><select name="childage" class="childage form-control"><option value="1">Up to 1 years</option><option value="2">1 to 2 years</option></select></div>');
     }
            });
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="countRoom">
     children
     <select onChange="childAge(this)">
      <option value="0"> 0 </option>
      <option value="1"> 1 </option>
      <option value="2"> 2 </option>
     </select>
   <input type="text" class="childcount" value="2" readonly>
     
    <div class="selectAge"></div>
   </div>
```

Comment: `childcount` is read-only, how you want to change this `input` value? in `html` before run?

Comment: @pedram yes. Actually I had a value for this input from Url. u consider it constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `$(document).ready` block and set the value of `select` with the value of `input`. Please note that you have to execute `change()` effect after, so that your code works properly.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.countRoom').find('select').val($('.childcount').val());
  $('.countRoom').find('select').change()
})
$(function() {
  $(".button-click-child a").on("click", function() {
    var button = $(this);
    var oldVal = parseInt(button.closest("ul").prev().val());
    var newVal = (button.text() == "+") ? oldVal + 1 : (oldVal > 0) ? oldVal - 1 : 0;
    button.closest("ul").prev().val(newVal);
    button.closest("ul").next().val(newVal+',');
    $(".cat_textbox").each(function() {
      var cat = $(this).prev('span').text();
      total_value += cat + ": " + $(this).val() + "، ";
    });

    if (oldVal < newVal) {
      $('.childDropdowns').append(createChildDropdown(newVal));
    } else if (oldVal > newVal) {
      destroyChildDropdown($('.childDropdowns'), newVal);
    }
  
  })
})
 function childAge(a){
   $(a).each(function(){
   age=$(a).val();
   
    $(a).closest(".countRoom").find(".selectAge").empty();
    for(var j=1;j<=age;j++){
     $(a).closest(".countRoom").css("width","100%").find(".selectAge").append('<div class="age"><label>Age of Child' + j + '</label><select name="childage" class="childage form-control"><option value="1">Up to 1 years</option><option value="2">1 to 2 years</option></select></div>');
     }
            });
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="countRoom">
     children
     <select onChange="childAge(this)">
      <option value="0"> 0 </option>
      <option value="1"> 1 </option>
      <option value="2"> 2 </option>
     </select>
   <input type="text" class="childcount" value="2" readonly>
     
    <div class="selectAge"></div>
   </div>
```

Comment: to set the value of `select` on page load

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

try this to select an option:

```
$('select option[value="'+$('.childcount').val()+'"]').attr('selected','selected');
```